# Setting onMarkerClickListener on different markers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3, android-snackbar

I want to set OnMarkerClickListener of different Markers. Here I want to print **i variable value of loop** whenever respective marker will get clicked. So I did by following way .. but it is not working , It display same last value **170** of loop on the Snackbar in every different marker click.. But I suppose to get 0,10,20,30....170 respectively in snackbar on different marker click.

Please help...

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;



        // SETTING MARKER
        for(int i=0;i<180;i=i+10) {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(i, i);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Position"+i));

            //ON MARKER CLICK
            final int finalI = i;

            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    Snackbar.make((View) findViewById(R.id.map),""+finalI,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Here is the marker which was created by loop
but I am getting same value to 170

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Resolve your problem you should have a marker array.

Try this:

First make your app to implement GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener
Then create a Marker array :

```
Marker[] marker = new Marker[20]; //change length of array according to you
```

then inside

```
onMapReady(){
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
 for(int i=0;i<180;i=i+10) {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(i, i);
            marker[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Position"+i));


        }
}
```

then finally

```
     @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
   //you can get assests of the clicked marker
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one way...

```
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            // SETTING MARKER
            for(int i=0;i<180;i=i+10) {
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(i, i);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Position"+i));

                }

        //ON MARKER CLICK
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            for(int i=0;i<180;i=i+10) {
                if (marker.getTitle().equals("Marker in Position" + i))
                    Snackbar.make((View) findViewById(R.id.map), "" + i, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }return true;
        }
    });
    }
```